# Dont run job when it is already running

Tags: liferay, quartz-scheduler, liferay-6

I have a job scheduled in Liferay, if for example this job is running every 5 minutes and needs more than 5 minutes to complete, how is it handled in Liferay?

What I have observed is that the job will just start again, this could result in problems for me.

Is it somehow possible to not trigger a job, when it is already running?

*using liferay 6.0.6

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `LockLocalServiceUtil` and its methods `lock()`, `unlock()` and `isLocked()`. Something like this:

```
try {
    if (LockLocalServiceUtil.isLocked()) {
        return;
    }
    LockLocalServiceUtil.lock();

    // do your job
} finally {
    LockLocalServiceUtil.unlock();
}
```

Locks are stored in database so there will be no problem in a cluster environment.

Comment: awesome, thank you!
could you provide a bit more information?
LockLocalServiceUtil.lock(long userId, String className, long key, String owner, boolean inheritable, long expirationTime) i guess the expirationTime is measured in mili seconds? what value is required in the owner field?

Comment: Yes you are right, expirationTime is measured in milis. Actually, I don't know your precise use case, but for me a `lock(String className, String key, String owner, boolean retrieveFromCache)` was always sufficient. The simplest way how to use it is to fill _className_ and _key_ parameters with your values (`isLocked()` method checks only according to these parameters) and fill _owner_ with some String constant (like "DEFAULT_OWNER") and _retrieveFromCache_ with false value. Then you can use `unlock(String className, String key) ` for unlocking and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best practice but here goes

```
    private static boolean runningJob = false;
@Override
public void receive(Message arg0) throws MessageListenerException {

    if(runningJob)
        return;

    runningJob = true; //marking that a job just started
    //Do stuff  { ....... } // this might take a while
    runningJob = false;
}
```

Comment: this won't work in a cluster i think :S so for me it is not a possible solution i could use. I did not mention in my question that it is clustered so you solutian is theoretically ok i guess... thanks for your input!